# hook_form_alter Add wrapping div around label and input

Tags: forms

Using hook_form_alter, for each field I want to wrap a div around the label and the input, leaving the help text (description) separate. Can hook_form_alter do this? Seemingly I can only add prefix and suffix to the wrapping div.

Comment: No, You have to implement hook_theme for this.

Comment: ok - can you point me in the right direction for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [theme_form_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) to achieve desired goal.

It returns HTML for a form element.

Each form element is wrapped in a DIV container

Comment: Thanks, looks close. But I can't see how the html is formed with this hook?